# nested grid areas not aligning properly

Tags: css, css-grid

I'm trying to recreate a CSS Grid Layout. When I declare the `grid-area` for each classname, the grid doesn't seem to want to render properly in the right places for `grid-area: aside;` and `grid-area: main;`. I assume this may be because these two are nested inside other elements?

Desired Result: https://codepen.io/chrisburton/full/YVrqRr/

[image]

Actual Result: https://codepen.io/chrisburton/pen/eWqJRQ

CSS:

```
.container {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-areas: "nav nav" 
                         "aside main"
                         "foot foot"
                         "footer footer";
    grid-template-columns: 18rem 1fr;
}

.nav { 
    grid-area: nav; 
    background: #FFAAAA;
}


.aside { 
    grid-area: aside; 
    background: #D46A6A; 
}

.main { 
    grid-area: main; 
    background: #AA3939; 
}

.article-footer { 
    grid-area: foot;
    background: #9A3939;
}

.footer {
    grid-area: footer;
    background: #801515;
}
```

Comment: To get much better browser support you could use Flexbox instead, so would that be of interest?

Comment: Here is a sample using Flexbox, let me know if it's useful and I'll post an answer. https://jsfiddle.net/m315vq21/

Comment: Browser support is not of any importance in my case. I think the problem is that `display: grid` only works on direct descendants. Therefore, you have to explicitly declare additional grids, in my case, on the first `article` element.

Comment: Yes, that you need, as it is only the immediate children of a grid (or flexbox) container that becomes grid (flex) items

Comment: @LGSon Thanks for chiming in. I really appreciate it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ... the grid doesn't seem to want to render properly in the right places for `grid-area: aside;` and `grid-area: main;`. I assume this may be because these two are nested inside other elements?

Yes. That is correct.

The scope of a [**grid formatting context**](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-grid-layout/#grid-model) is limited to the parent-child relationship.

This means that a grid container is always the parent and a grid item is always the child. Grid properties work only within this relationship.

As stated in the spec:

> [**6. Grid
>   Items**](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-grid-layout/#grid-items)
>
> Each in-flow child of a grid container becomes a grid item.

Descendants of a grid container beyond the children are not grid items and will not accept grid properties. Also, as implied in the spec language above, [children that are out-of-flow](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-grid-layout/#static-position) (i.e., absolutely positioned) are not grid items, either.

Bottom line: You will always need to apply `display: grid` or `display: inline-grid` to a parent in order for grid properties to work on the child.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Makes more sense now.